# How to get clone html hidden id while clicks on cancel button

Tags: jquery

I have clone html data here i need to delete one record then i need to get id from that cancel record.
 Here is my html code:

```
   <div id="Allergies" class="clone">
        <div class="copy">
            <input type="hidden" id="allergyId" value="">
         /*rest of the code will be the html data*/
      <a class="addallergy" id="addallergy">Save and Add Allergy</a>
      <a class="removeallergy" id="removeallergy">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    <div>
```

Here is my javascript code:

```
 var p=$('.copy').length;
  var h=0;
        for(var i=0 ; i<data.allergies.length ; i++){
          var cloned = $(".copy:first").clone(true)
              .     .appendTo('#Allergies').addClass("childAllergyClass" + (i + 1));
            $(".childAllergyClass"+ ++h+" #allergyId").val(data.allergies[i].allergyId);
     }
```

Now My html code will be:

```
 <div id="Allergies" class="clone">
        <div class="copy childAllergyClass1">
            <input type="hidden" id="allergyId" value="123">
         /*rest of the code will be the html data*/
           <a class="addallergy" id="addallergy">Save and Add Allergy</a>
           <a class="removeallergy" id="removeallergy">Cancel</a>            
       </div>
        <div class="copy childAllergyClass2">
            <input type="hidden" id="allergyId" value="124">
         /*rest of the code will be the html data*/
            <a class="addallergy" id="addallergy">Save and Add Allergy</a>
            <a class="removeallergy" id="removeallergy">Cancel</a>    
       </div>
    <div>
```

If we have length is 2 then two allergies displayed in the UI.If i click on cancel the current record will be disappeared by using the code

```
    $(".removeallergy").click(function(e) {
         $(this).closest(".copy").fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $(this).remove();
          });
    });
```

then I need particular record id for inactive the current record status in database.

Please help me how to get id from the cancel record or else any better idea to inactive the record in database.

Comment: Off-topic: it's "life-threat *en* ing".

Comment: What exactly is your question?!!

Comment: You have two input elements with the same id?

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id on a page.

Comment: Here i displayed using id value based on this $(".childAllergyClass"+ ++h+" #allergyId").val(data.allergies[i].allergyId) now my code working fine and functionality also working fine. now i need to cancel the record i need to get particular record Id. is it possible to get the current Id?

Comment: HI T J I have two records,now i clicks on cancel button now my record will be removed from the UI at the same time i update the particular record in database also.

Comment: Hi chridam yes i have two id's with same name and my functionality will working good.Now my question is when i clicks on cancel button then the particular record will be disappear at the same time i need to update that record status in database.

Comment: Hi every one please check once Javascript code.you will understand clearly.

Comment: Hi Dan, MY code functionality working fine,i am not bother about id's here .if i click's on cancel button then my current record will be disappear at the same time i need to inactive the status of particular record in the database.

Comment: Here the length will be 2 then java script code will create exact copy of same parent record so that the id will be creates 2 times.so saving and updating using that id code works fine for me in my application.Now the problem is only about Cancel button.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do. Post a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer: in my project i use similar id's and my application works fine.

```
$(".removeallergy").click(function(e) {
     $(this).closest(".copy").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        var abc = $("#allergyId",this).val();
           $(this).remove();
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here iam using similar id's and get the data successfully.please check the below code

```
<div>
     <div class="duplicate1">
        Name1:<input type="text"  name="duplicateName" id="duplicateName"/>
        Id1:<input type="text" name="duplicateId" id="duplicateId"/>
     </div>
      <div class="duplicate2">
         Name2:<input type="text" name="duplicateName" id="duplicateName"/>
         Id2:<input type="text"  name="duplicateId" id="duplicateId"/>
      </div>
     <button type="button" onclick="javascript:saveDuplicates();">Save</button>
</div>
```

Here is java script code:

```
function saveDuplicates(){
        var duplicate = {
                duplicateName1 : $(".duplicate1 #duplicateName").val(),
                duplicateId1 :  $(".duplicate1 #duplicateId").val(),
                duplicateName2 :  $(".duplicate2 #duplicateName").val(),
                duplicateId2 :  $(".duplicate2 #duplicateId").val()
        };
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(duplicate);
        alert(jsonString);
    }
```